# MySQL select 3 first characters and replace

Tags: mysql

I have a simple problem, which is causing me problems

I have a column in mysql with names, and I'd like to replace these by the first three characters in the name. 
So for instance 'Jacob' -> 'Jac'.

I know of the LEFT command, which can do this for me, but I can't seem to update the column with the output. Like I can do a select, and then get the correct output, but I can't update the desired column with the output :(

I tried:

```
REPLACE INTO mytable(shortnames) SELECT LEFT(names,3) FROM mytable;
```

Comment: Show us the select query and the update query you have tried

Comment: `replace into` statement inserts a new record, or in case of a duplicate conflict, deletes the old record and inserts the new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need

```
UPDATE mytable SET names = LEFT(names,3);
```

Comment: No problem. Please consider marking this as the answer if it resolved your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a simple UPDATE query

```
UPDATE table SET names = LEFT(names,3)
```

However it might be a good idea to create another column at least temporarily and do

```
UPDATE table SET short_name = LEFT(names,3)
```

Then either keep both columns or drop the column you dont want any more.

Of course you could leave the name as it is and when you only want the short version just select it like that from the `names` column like this

```
SELECT LEFT(names,3) as short_name from table
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need

```
UPDATE `table` SET `field` = LEFT(`field`, 3)
```